# What is object type body mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

From [Bootstrap-Timepicker](https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/), appendWidgetTo has the option of "body" for custom placement, one of the samples gives the usage : `appendWidgetTo: 'body',`
Does that mean anything to Javascript gurus? I would have assumed if appending to an object either the id of the html element or getting a refrence to object and using that as a parameter would make sense.

from the sample I can't see what other parameters could have been used to get an idea, finally if 'body' is the only acceptable value, then a bool value would make more sense here?

Answer (score 3):

When you call the `body` element, you would do so as `$('body')`, right?

Well in `appendWidgetTo: 'body'`, it's simply taking that value, if you had it as `appendWidgetTo: '#myId'` here, then there would be a substitution to `$('#myId')` instead of `body`.